# Is there a perl module to convert .bin file to .pem file

Tags: perl, ssl, cpan

I want to convent my certificates from .bin file format to .pem file format, is there a perl module that I can use.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the harm in using `openssl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use openssl ?

Just call openssl from within perl (use system() )